# Excel Data Currency Formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel

Our Excel spreadsheet is set to US region, English. When I email it to someone in India, the formatting of currency data in the sheet update to Indian currency from US currency.

How do I keep the formatting in US currency?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "numbers update to Indian currency". Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1443130/edit) and post links to before and after screen caps? (you can upload to http://imgur.com)

Comment: any sample of how the mentioned currency look like.. before and after?

Answer (score 1):

*Our Excel spreadsheet is set to US region*

Not sure what you mean by that.  However, if you want to maintain language specific currency formatting when the worksheet goes to a different region, try setting a language specific format for the cells.

In other words, a cell format of:  `$#,##0.00`  will default to the windows regional setting of the displaying computer.

But a cell format of:  `[$$-en-US]#,##0.00` should maintain the US format even internationally.

You can find these formats in the cell format numberformat dialog under Currency or Accounting.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way.
[>9999999] _ [$₹-en-IN] * ##,##,##,##0_ ;[>99999] _ [$₹-en-IN] * ##,##,##0_ ;_ [$₹-en-IN] * ##,##0_ ;_ @_

it will make Symbol to appear left alligned like usual accounting format, and make numbers appear on right side

Comment: What are those weird (non-ASCII) characters next to the dollarsigns?